# is there anyway i can split a string up by " " delimiters and put them into a 2D array

Tags: c, arrays

given the input

- line[0] = "how are you"
- line[1] = "i am good"
- line[2] = "is this cool"

given those 3 input i want to make a 2D array of string like so

- data[0][3] = {"how", "are", "you"}
- data[1][3] = {"i" ,"am", "good"}
- data[2][3] = {"is", "this", "cool"}

I have tried using memcpy like so:

```
int i, k, tok = 0;    
char *line[3];
char *data[3][3];

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(k = 0; k < strlen(line[i]); k++){
            if(line[i][k] == ' '){
                len = k-start;
                data[i][tok] = malloc(len);
                memset(data[i][tok],'\0',len);
                memcpy(data[i][tok],&line[i][start],len);
                start = k+1;
                tok++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You may want to look into strtok() function. It is designed for this.

Comment: 1) `tok` and `start` needs  reset. 2) allocate +1 needs for `'\0'`

Comment: strtok() breaks the original string, so I would have to make a copy of the string if i wanted to restore the original

Comment: also check word of last of line.

Comment: Thank that solved the problem, I thought i added that part but i place it in the wrong spot =\